# How can I delete my list row by clicking on button in each row of the LISTVIEW

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-gui

I have a list view with custom array adapter. I want to get delete the item when delete button clicked.But I am not able to fix it out. Even my app getting die when I click on delete button. I am not getting any idea. My codes are as follows-

Code:-

```
package com.abc_fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.abc.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment_ListviewContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private static ArrayList listDetail;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
Context context;
public Fragment_ListviewContactAdapter(Context Fragment, ArrayList results)
{
listDetail = results;
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Fragment);

}




@Override
public int getCount()
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return listDetail.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return listDetail.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return arg0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ViewHolder holder;
if(convertView == null)
{

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listitem, null);
holder = new ViewHolder(); //Atomholderpayment
// holder.ListviewDashBoard = listDetail.get(position);


holder.orderno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.OrderNo_text);
holder.dispatchTo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchTo_text);
holder.dealerN = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dealerName_text);
holder.orderT = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_text);
holder.amountT = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Amount_text);
holder.removeButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
//holder.removeButton.setTag(holder.ListviewDashBoard);
//holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
//convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
convertView.setTag(holder);
/* holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
listDetail.remove(pos);
Fragment_ListviewContactAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

});*/


} else
{
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
Fragment_listViewDashboard ListviewDashBoard =listDetail.get(position);
holder.orderno.setText(listDetail.get(position).getOrderno());
holder.dispatchTo.setText(listDetail.get(position).getDispatchTo());
holder.dealerN.setText(listDetail.get(position).getDealerN());
holder.orderT.setText(listDetail.get(position).getOrderT());
holder.amountT.setText(listDetail.get(position).getAmountT());
holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "*************************************************");
Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});

return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
TextView orderno, dispatchTo, dealerN,orderT, amountT ;
Button removeButton;


}

}
```

Comment: u pass arraylist in adapter so when u click on listview remove the item from Arraylist And Update the Adapter

Comment: Try to call listDetail.remove(position); and after call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: There is a lot of sample projects related to the swipe to delete

Comment: Thanks @HareshChhelana it was quite helpful for me :)

Comment: @Khanna,Glad to help you and can you please approve and upvote ans if is useful to you.

Comment: That I have already done!! @HareshChhelana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

First define **position** as **final** in getView() parameter then try to remove list item from you list data holder **listDetail** using **remove** method and notify your adapter using **notifyDataSetChanged** method like :

```
holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{ 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      listDetail.remove(position);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
      Log.i("Delete Button Clicked",*************************************************");
      Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When you click on delete button implement below code:

```
YOURLISTVIEW.removeViewAt(position);
YOURARRAY.remove(position);
YOURADAPTER.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

OnClick of delete button  first you have to remove position from your arraylist  and then notify to your adapter like:

```
holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
@Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      _arrayList.remove(position);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});
```

Or you can make a method to reset adapter into your list like:

```
public void _resetAdapter(ArrayList<String> _list){
  // Set your adapter here and pass _list in your adapter
}
```

And call this method like:

```
  holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      _arrayList.remove(position);
       _resetAdapter(_arrayList);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on delete button....you should perform these things
1. Remove Item from your array list or array or database....
2. Then refresh your layout screen by displaying the list again....(put your all display list code in a method and then call it again)...

Hope this help you.....